# Writing outside the storage of a local variable?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, type-conversion, inline-assembly

I've got this code :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char b, c;
    _asm{
        mov word ptr b, 512;
    }
    printf("b=%d c=%d\n", b, c);

}
```

The output of the code is **b = 0; c = -52**.

My question is why is the **c = -52**? I can't figure out.

I understand that using **word** I change b from **char to short**. But why **c = -52** ?

Comment: I think that you should set some initial value to c, before You start making assumption that it was your asm code that changed its value. I have seen that some compilers add empty place between variables, when not asked for release code, to sanitize memory usage

Comment: It's true that I can change 512 with every number and the c will be the same. So it may be -52 beucase I didn't set some initial value to c?

Comment: it is not required for stack variables be pre set with any value. Unless you write something to it, such variable may store 0, some other initial value or just random garbage that some other function left in stack.

Comment: You can't guarantee that a compiler will place `b` and `c` on the stack in the order you placed it in your code, and you can't assume that the compiler might not put bytes between `b` and `c` if it so chooses. If you were to place `b` and `c` inside a struct then you might get the results you are looking for. I suspect you were hoping to see b=0 and c=2. Because `b` and `c` may not necessarily be one after another on the stack, and the stack variables were not initialized, `c` will have whatever  garbage is on the stack.

Comment: so -52 is only some garbace from the stack.

Comment: Yup.  It's clearly not from the store of `0x200` to `b`'s address.  If `c` had been stored at the byte right after `b`, it would be `2`.  If you disassemble the compiler output, you'll see exactly what it does.

Comment: -52 is a magic value.  It is 0xcc, the value used to initialize variables when you build your program with /RTC.  Turned by default in the Debug build and designed to catch initialization bugs.  So it simply means that you are reading an uninitialized value.  And have not managed to stomp it with your asm code.